# Nested JSON on Android with volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I want to make a post request with volley to a REST API.

This is the code.

```
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, 
            new Response.Listener<String>() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.e("Response", response);
                }
            }
        ) {     
         @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
            {  
                    Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
                    params.put("id_market", "-1");  
                    params.put("id_store", "1");
                    Log.e("OPE", params.toString() );
                    return params;  
            }




}
```

and i need something like this.

```
JSONParams={
"header": {
    "id_market": -1,
    "id_user_from": 1,
},
"detail": [
    {
        "id_product": 1,
        "id_market": -1,

    }
]
```

}

so, how can i make a nested JSON using volley?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Receiving JSON data from a volley request, or sending JSON data with volley?

Answer (score 1):

From your code sample, you can use `JsonObjectRequest` instead of `StringRequest`:

```
final JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject("{\"header\": {\"id_market\": -1,\"id_user_from\": 1,},\"detail\": [{\"id_product\": 1,\"id_market\": -1,}]");
new JsonObjectRequest(URL, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { ... });
```

A working example will look like this:

```
    try {
        String url = "";
        JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject("{\"header\": {\"id_market\": -1,\"id_user_from\": 1,},\"detail\": [{\"id_product\": 1,\"id_market\": -1,}]");
        new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonRequest, new Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // Handle response
            }
        }, null /* Or handle error case */);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //Handle Excpetion
    }
```

Comment: You have to explain more!

Comment: ok, maybe i didn't explain good, i need send JSON data to a server, the body of the JSON has to have that form. i tried with your example but jsonBody has a error.

Comment: Previous post Edited. FYI, try to give a more precise information. "This does not work" is not a precise information. Give us the error associated, what you're trying to achieve, what you should have, etc.

Comment: first the jsonBody apparently have to go on try catch , and then "Value Query of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject".

Comment: So, if it need a try catch, why don't you put a try catch? Are you familiar with java?